# R Inverse of sparse matrix vs regular inverse in R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse

I am constructing a matrix C and its class is "dgCMatrix" since I use the bdiag function in the Matrix library in R. However inverting teh sparse matrix (one) is gving different results than inverting the same matrix without being of class sparse (two). One is giving a wrong answer. Does anyone know why

```
## rm(list=ls())
library(Matrix)

cy11=function(a,b,H){
  d=outer(a,b,`-`);I=outer(a,b,`==`)
  H[1]^2*exp(-0.25*d^2/H[2]^2) +  I*H[3]^2
}
x0=c(1,1,0.05)
n1=25;n2=100
data=matrix( rnorm(n1*n2,mean=0,sd=5), n1, n2)
slast=seq(0,10,length.out=26)
z=list();Z=list()

for(i in 1:n2){
    a=data[,i]
    z[[i]]=cy11(a,a,x0)
    }
for(i in 1:n2)
{
  a=data[,i]
  Z[[i]]=cy11(a,slast,x0)
}
A=bdiag(z)
D=cy11(slast,slast,x0)
B=do.call(rbind,Z)

C=rbind(cbind(A,B),cbind(t(B),D))

one=solve(C)
two=solve(as.matrix(C))
```

Comment: I must admit confusion about how inverting a diagonal matrix could cause issues. I'll also admit that I slept in for many of my classes in linear algebra. I'm not willing to paste that coed (er, code) into my console because of its first line. This certainly looks to produce the expected result: `solve( matrix(c(7,0,0,5),2) )`

Comment: With Matrix 1-2.3 `all.equal(one, two)` gives me TRUE using  "R version 3.2.3 Patched (2016-01-12 r69945)" on Windows 8.1.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I just changed (length.out=26) and you will see the difference

Comment: @G.Grothendieck it seems when the length of slast is greater than n1, the sparse function in R has some issues

Comment: `all.equal(one, two)` still gives me TRUE.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck all.equal(one, two) gives a length mismatch, try sum(abs(one-two)) = 887, this shows they are not the same

Comment: `sum(abs(one-two))` gives me 0.  Did you try the same version of Matrix that I am using?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Matrix 1-2.3 ? I am working with Matrix 1.2-4

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I tried Matrix 1-2.3 and still does not work